# Bootstrap Carousel adjusting during transition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My bootstrap carousel is adjusting after during the transitions between images.

here is the page:
http://eckroth.aspdotnetstorefront.active-e.net/t-hometest9.aspx

carousel code:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"><img alt="Slide1" src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/cccccc/ffffff" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"><img alt="Slide2" src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/999999/cccccc" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"><img alt="Slide3" src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/dddddd/333333" />
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-controls"><a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left fa-lg"></i></a><a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-lg"></i></a></div>
</div>
</div>

Style sheet:
}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:auto;
  height:36px;
  width:36px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}
.carousel-control.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0%), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
}
.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 50%;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  font-family: serif;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: -30%;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  margin: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
  text-shadow: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicons-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .glyphicons-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

## myCarousel {

```
padding:5px;

background: #428BCA;
```

}

## myCarousel  .carousel-caption {

```
top:auto;

width:auto;

right:auto;

bottom:0px;

left:0;

padding:20px;

background:rgba(255,255,255,0.65);

text-align:center;

height:auto;

width:100%;

color:#432A18;/*#FFF*/

text-shadow:none;
```

}

## myCarousel  .carousel-caption h2 {

```
color:#428BCA;

margin-top:0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like since posting this you've implemented a max-height to your carousel-inner class. It seems like it works better if you use 400px, but that's the solution I was going to suggest.

```
.carousel-inner {
max-height: 400px !important;
```

}